# How to prevent the default browser input validation in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

[image]

I just need to remove "Please fill out this field" without removing a "required" attribute. I have my custom validation, so I have to use a "required" attribute in order to know when the text field is valid or not.

```
      <input
        name="name"
        value="name"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        id="name"
        type="text"
        autoComplete="off"
        required
      ></input>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove required attribute from input . use that input

```
<input
    name="name"
    value="name"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    id="name"
    type="text"
    autoComplete="off"

  />
```

input field is self closed field means `<input />`

Comment: After, remove a "required" attribute, I cannot check in css if the input is valid or not, so I have to leave it.

Comment: what are you using in css ? you can use name attribute instead of required attribute for css

Comment: .text-field input:focus + .label-name .content-name,
.text-field input:valid + .label-name .content-name {
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gold;
}

.text-field input:focus + .label-name::after,
.text-field input:valid + .label-name::after {
  transform: translateX(0%);
} 

So, as you can see I am trying to check if the input is valid. Is there alternative way to check it without a "required" attribute?

Comment: when you remove html means either you are not using validation or you are creating you own validation , in case of your own validation change css with validation ... on validation add some class and target that class

Comment: if you remove required then there will no way for checking the validation with css , you have to use javascript in react for validation and add or remove css with the javascript

Comment: This is not a global solution. It does not completely solve the problem. What if you use type=email ?